# How to prevent Google Drive from OCR scanning your image files?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

I realized that image files in Google Drive are 'ocr scanned' for words (letters, numbers). 
Because they appear in Google Drive search results afterwards...
Is it possible to disable this automatic 'ocr scanning' and indexing? For example for security reasons.

Comment: Probably not. I believe that Google scans all one's documents in Google Drive (which also prevents piracy or storage of illegal files). The answer to this question should explain in detail the reasons why Google does that.